# Vision Problem vs Visual Problem

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, subcontinental-english

I have a problem with those 2 words. What is the difference between the *vision problem* and *visual problem*? Or Do they mean the same? I Googled both terms, but the search results are pretty much the same.

Actually I am colour blind (strong deutan). So how can I express that? Is it "I have *Visual Problem*" or "I have *Vision Problem*"?. Which one fits in this case ?

If I want to ask another person about his eyes, how should I ask? "Do You have *Vision Problems*?" or "Do you have *Visual Problems*?"

Comment: I think vision problems would refer directly to your eyes (the actual organs) while visual problems could be used for equipment (projectors, screens, etc.)

Comment: You have ***a** vision problem* if there's something wrong with your sight.  A *visual problem* also occurs (significantly less often), but might be misinterpreted as "a problem presented visually". Omitting the article is a "non-standard" feature of Indian English, but it's perfectly normal to pluralize as *He has vision problems*, or recast as *He has problems / a problem with his vision / [eye]sight*.

Comment: 'Vision' is a noun (the eyes), while 'visual' is an adjective (the quality of the image).  It is easier to adjust the latter.  {I know; I have glaucoma}

Comment: @ Aml , What does that {I know; I have glaucoma} mean ? Are you saying something like I can say 'I know ; I have colour blindness' or something else or you have eye problem like me that's why you are saying  {I know; I have glaucoma} . Regards NB :)

Comment: @ FumbleFingers , What does 'Omitting the article is a "non-standard" feature of Indian English' mean ? Regards NB :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vision problem means it is related to the way we *perceive* something

A visual problem means it is related to a physical thing we can see.

Therefore, you should use a `vision problem`.